# mod_security and apt-get

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-9.04, mod-security

hi can anyone help me with mod_security configuration...

I have installed mod_security on ubuntu 9.04 lamp server,... but now I want to install anything and type apt-get install program, it keeps saying that they all depend on mod_security... and cannot be installed.

Answer (score 1):

You have messed up something.

try apt's superpowers

`apt-get -f install`